# Cursors from multiple tables plsql

Tags: loops, for-loop, plsql, cursor

need some help with the following task.

I have 3 tables: active_t, company_t, element_t

active_t has 2 columns: instancename and active. It basically contains a list of schemas and active will either be 1(meaning active)  or 0 (not active).
I need to query this table to fetch list of active schemas. Then based on each active schema I need to find list of active company codes (from column comp_code) from company_t. Then for each active company I need to insert data from the table element_t into a 4th table (target_t);

Point to note here is that the tables company_t and element_t exist in all schemas.

I tried to first create a cursor c1 like : select instancename from active_t where active=1;

but now not sure how to use this cursor for the next steps.
Help will be greatly appreciated.

One thing that I missed to add is that we have created a separate schema "TESTUSER" which has the table active_t. While the tables company_t and element_t are existing in each country specific schema. This TESTUSER has been given select grant on company_t and element_t.

The table active_t looks like this:

```
INSTANCENAME    ACTIVE
IN              1
SI              0
```

company_t looks like this (for active country IN)

```
CODE    DELDATE
1111    null    
2222    null
3333    null    
4444    null
```

The code will first have to check this table and go for the schema IN( since active=1). For this schema the code will have to then get a list of active companies from the table company_t from that country schema (IN in this case).
Company_t and element_t does not have a column which identifies the schema.

Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Comment: INSTANCENAME ACTIVE
IN                               1
SI                               0

Comment: Are the 'schemas' in ACTIVE_T related to Oracle user accounts? It would help to see `create table` and `insert` statements with sample data.

Comment: Yes those are user accounts. Below is the DDL for the table:                                                        CREATE TABLE active_country_t (
    instancename VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
    active       NUMBER(1)
)
TABLESPACE users;

Comment: What is the purpose of this task? I ask because your proposal to use cursors is a poor choice - presumably you would end up nesting cursors and inserting the data row-by-agonising-row - when writing code for a production system. As a learning exercise it's just about ok, if the aim is to understand how to work with cursors. If your task is for anything other than a learning exercise, I would suggest you write a select statement that joins your tables and returns the results you need to insert. Then you can use that query in an `insert into ... select ...` statement.

Comment: @Yuvraj Please edit your question to include a complete test case that others can try out, so that we can see for ourselves what isn't working and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If we take as sample data the folowing CTEs:

```sql
WITH
    active_t AS
        (
            Select 'A'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 0 "IS_ACTIVE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'B'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 1 "IS_ACTIVE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'C'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 1 "IS_ACTIVE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'D'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 0 "IS_ACTIVE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'E'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 1 "IS_ACTIVE" From Dual 
        ),
    company_t AS
        (
            Select 'A'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 101 "COMPANY_CODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'A'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 102 "COMPANY_CODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'B'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 201 "COMPANY_CODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'B'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 202 "COMPANY_CODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'B'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 203 "COMPANY_CODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'C'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 301 "COMPANY_CODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'D'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 401 "COMPANY_CODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'D'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 402 "COMPANY_CODE" From Dual Union All
            Select 'E'  "INSTANCE_NAME", 501 "COMPANY_CODE" From Dual 
        ),
    element_t AS
        (
            Select 101 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_11_A' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_12_A' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 101 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_13_A' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 202 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_21_B' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 203 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_22_B' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 301 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_31_C' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 401 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_41_D' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 401 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_42_D' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 401 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_44_D' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 401 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_45_D' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 401 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_46_D' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 501 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_51_E' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 501 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_52_E' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 505 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_53_E' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select 501 "COMPANY_CODE", 'EL_54_E' "ELEMENT_ID" From Dual 
        )
```

... then (if I got it right) the main SQL (your Cursor) could be like this:

```sql
SELECT
  a.INSTANCE_NAME "INSTANCE_NAME",
  c.COMPANY_CODE "COMPANY_CODE",
  e.ELEMENT_ID "ELEMENT_ID"
FROM
  active_t a
INNER JOIN
  company_t c ON(c.INSTANCE_NAME = a.INSTANCE_NAME)
INNER JOIN
  element_t e ON(e.COMPANY_CODE = c.COMPANY_CODE)
WHERE
  a.IS_ACTIVE = 1
```

resulting as

```sql
--  INSTANCE_NAME COMPANY_CODE ELEMENT_ID
--  ------------- ------------ ----------
--  B                      202 EL_21_B    
--  B                      203 EL_22_B    
--  C                      301 EL_31_C    
--  E                      501 EL_51_E    
--  E                      501 EL_52_E    
--  E                      501 EL_54_E
```

All of this is just for generating some sample data to work with. Now, if you want to use the data in a PL/SQL block then you can do it like below:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    CURSOR cur IS 
        SELECT
          a.INSTANCE_NAME "INSTANCE_NAME",
          c.COMPANY_CODE "COMPANY_CODE",
          e.ELEMENT_ID "ELEMENT_ID"
        FROM
          active_t a
        INNER JOIN
          company_t c ON(c.INSTANCE_NAME = a.INSTANCE_NAME)
        INNER JOIN
          element_t e ON(e.COMPANY_CODE = c.COMPANY_CODE)
        WHERE
          a.IS_ACTIVE = 1;
    curSet    cur%ROWTYPE;
Begin
    OPEN cur;     -- Open cursor
    LOOP    
        FETCH cur INTO curSet;    -- fetch cursor row by row into curSet variable
        EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;   -- exit Loop when there are no rows left in the cursor
        -- Here you can do whatever you want with fetched cursor row
        -- I will just print the data out so you can see how to refference values from curSet variable
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Instance: ' || curSet.INSTANCE_NAME || ' Company Code: ' || curSet.COMPANY_CODE || ' Element: ' || curSet.ELEMENT_ID);
    END LOOP;  
    CLOSE cur;   -- close cursor
End;
```

DBMS_OUTPUT is:

```sql
--  anonymous block completed
--  Instance: B Company Code: 202 Element: EL_21_B
--  Instance: B Company Code: 203 Element: EL_22_B
--  Instance: C Company Code: 301 Element: EL_31_C
--  Instance: E Company Code: 501 Element: EL_51_E
--  Instance: E Company Code: 501 Element: EL_52_E
--  Instance: E Company Code: 501 Element: EL_54_E
```

Regards...